# Android Studio and Gradle - seemingly misleading warning regarding testCompile, testImplementation, testApi

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I get these two lines when compiling an old Android project using latest Android Studio (3.1.4):

```
WARNING: Configuration 'testCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation' and 'testApi'.
WARNING: Configuration 'testApi' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.
```

I understand what they mean and how I can fix these warnings, there are also questions explaining it, but I can't any reference to 'testApi' anywhere on developer.android.com. Is it an error in warnings or was there testApi command? Was it added alongside 'testImplementation' and was later deprecated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously we used testCompile but as per the last Gradle update Android Studio sometimes shows this messages though we edit the gradle file with new keywords.Now the "testApi" was not there in gradle as per my own experience.I think this error message is a fault.

Comment: Since the question mentioned two contradictory warning messages. Can you please say, which message is faulty?
Or asked differently: can we use testApi?

Comment: The second message is coming faulty in this case.There were no testApi in previous versions of gradle...compile,testCompile,androidTestCompile have been deprecated and therefore one has to edit them as implementation,testImplementation and androidTestImplementation respectively.

Comment: @PeterF I believe that both of them are faulty. First one informs that "testApi" was introduced. Second says that it was deprecated. But there was no "testApi" all along as I understand, so second line was probably only added because "testApi" was erroneously introduced by first one.

Comment: @Sana Thanks for your answer. I want to note that compile can be replaced by either implementation or api.